# C Program: A array containts items ID's, B array contains sold items find C array which contains unsold items

Tags: c, arrays

This is my program but doesn't work as it is incomplete.

```
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a[]={101,102,103,104,107,110};
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);

    int b[]={102,103,101};
    int m = sizeof(b) / sizeof(int);

    int c[20];
    static int k=0;
    int flag;

    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {                          
        if(a[0]!=b[j])
        {
             c[k]=b[j];
             printf("c[%d]=%d\n",k,c[k]);
             k++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I need to find the C Array which contains unsold items.

**Note: No sorting should be used.**

I tried several hours trying to find a solution, but I cannot come up with any thing simple. Would be great if someone helps.

Comment: Suggest you write down an algorithm on paper first before attempting to convert it to code. Show/describe the algorithm that you are trying to implement.

Comment: You need to compare each element of `a` with `b` and then pick .

Comment: `if(a[0]!=b[j])` that is clearly not going to work since you are always comparing with the same `a` element. A simple solution is likely to involve a nested loop to compare each element in `a` with every element in `b` (short circuit when a match occurs of course).

Comment: @kaylum I used that because, it display all the elements in B to C except first element of A (i.e) 101. Now C contains 102,103. So I though of comparing A and C to find unsold elements.

Comment: What do you mean "displays all the elements"? The first element is in no way special as far as the algorithm is concerned. You need to do the same operation for every element of `a`.

Comment: @kaylum https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/BoisterousLaughableDataMetro I managed to remove only 101, but need to remove 102,103 from C and Add 104,107,110 to C since its not sold.

Comment: I already told you what is wrong. How can you possibly expect to remove any of the other elements if you only look at one element? Like I said, work out the algorithm first.

Comment: "unsold items" What's that supposed to mean? Your program contains nothing but one-letter nonsense variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you like to find this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int a[]={101,102,103,104,107,110};
int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);

int b[]={102,103,101};
int m = sizeof(b) / sizeof(int);

int c[20];
static int k=0;
int flag;
for(int i =0;i<n;i++){

    int f=0;
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {                          
        if(a[i]==b[j])
        {
            f=1;
        }

    }
    if(f==0)
    {
        c[k]=a[i];
        printf("c[%d]=%d\n",k,c[k]);
        k++;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
c[0]=104
c[1]=107
c[2]=110
```

Comment: works great, thanks for this. I'll take a look at this, to learn from your program.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** The accepted answer works well but it will execute in quadratic time => O(n ^2) which will be slower than this solution.

Have you considered using the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)? It works well for counting problems like yours.

> if n items are put into m containers, with n > m, then at least one container must contain more than one item.

In your case, put all the items in Array "a" into a container (an array) with the indexes corresponding to the actual numbers in a(using a for loop. Operation is => O(n)). Go through the container array and mark all the positions that contain items in b. Operation will also be O(n). Finally, go through the container array a third time and pick all your unsold item.

Here is the code (I didn't test it but I think it should work well):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int a[]={101,102,103,104,107,110};
int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);

int b[]={102,103,101};
int m = sizeof(b) / sizeof(int);

int c[20];
static int k=0;
int flag;

int largestNumInA = 0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

    if(largestNumInA < a[i])
        largestNumInA = a[i];
}

int solutionSet[largestNumInA]; // this is our container

for(int j=0;j<n;j++){ // Time Complexity => O(n)

    solutionSet[a[j]] = 1; // flag off the original sample items as 1..
}

for(int k=0;k<m;k++){ // Time Complexity => O(n)

    solutionSet[b[k]] = -1; // flag off the sold items as -1..
}

for(int x=0;x<largestNumInA;x++){ // Time Complexity => O(n)

    if(solutionSet[x] == 1){ // unsold items...
        c[k] = x;
        printf("c[%d]=%d\n",k,x);
        k++;
    }
}
return 0;

}
```